# Getting `get` only list property gives null reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

I have a script in my Unity project which acts a "manager" of sorts, tracking the position of obstacles and exposing a get only List called CurrentObstaclePositions. I want the main player script to find the reference to this list, so that it can easily consume the position data without me having to add that logic into the player script. However, in the way that I've set up my two scripts now, trying to get a reference to CurrentObstaclePositions gives me null no matter what I try.

I've made sure that the call to GetComponent is working. The reference to the manager script is fine, but specifically getting this property doesn't work.

This is what the relevant part of the main player script looks like.

```
void Awake()
    {
        obstacleManager = GameObject.Find("Moving Obstacles").GetComponent<MovingObstacleManager>();
        // Get current moving obstacle positions
        // ****(fails here with NullReference Exception)
        movingObstaclePositions = obstacleManager.CurrentObstaclePositions;
    }
```

And this is what the MovingObstacleManager script looks like.

```
public class MovingObstacleManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> _movingObstacleGameObjects { get; set; }
    public List<Obstacle> MovingObstacles { get; private set; }

    public List<Vector3> CurrentObstaclePositions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.MovingObstacles.ConvertAll((Obstacle obs) => obs.CurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    internal List<Vector3> LastObstaclePositions
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Vector3>(MovingObstacles.ConvertAll<Vector3>((Obstacle obs) => obs.LastPosition));
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _movingObstacleGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        MovingObstacles = new List<Obstacle>();
        // Add all children GameObjects to own private list
        // (for use in checking if new obstacles are present later)
        foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform)
        {
            _movingObstacleGameObjects.Add(child.gameObject);
            // To main exposed list, create new Obstacle object
            // Instatiating them automatically stores their position
            MovingObstacles.Add(new Obstacle(child.gameObject));
        }
    }
}
```

May or may not be relevant, but the implementation of the Obstacle object is like this.

```
public class Obstacle
{
    public GameObject gameObject { get; private set; }
    private Vector3 _currentPosition;
    public Vector3 CurrentPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            // Store the current position as the last position before updating
            LastPosition = _currentPosition;
            _currentPosition = value;
        }
    }
    public Vector3 LastPosition {get; private set;}

    public Obstacle(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        this.gameObject = gameObject;
        this._currentPosition = new Vector3(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
        // Use Vector3 with components of float.MaxValue to mean a "null" vector, since Vector3 is non-nullable value type
        // Since _currentPosition is set to this "null" value, when we update CurrentPosition to the obstacle's  first position
        // the "null" vector will be recorded as the obstacle's LastPosition
        this.CurrentPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    }
}
```

What's going on here? I want movingObstaclePositions to hold whatever value obstacleManager.CurrentObstaclePositions returns, but the reference seems to be null.

Comment: @mjwillis It is not. I verified this by adding a hello method to the MovingObstacleManager class. obstacleManager.hello() worked fine. It’s specially the assignment from the property which fails.

Comment: `return this.MovingObstacles.ConvertAll((Obstacle obs) => obs.CurrentPosition);` Put a breakpoint on that line. Run to it. What is the value of `this.MovingObstacles.Count`?

Comment: Possible `MovingObstacles` is null , It initialize on  `Start() `, maybe it not initialize when you call that ? you find that on `Awake()` It's before  `Start() `

Comment: Generally I find that if I need to use `GameObject.Find` I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Just to confirm, is your Player object instantiated after the MovingObstacleManager? Because otherwise, Awake() precedes Start() in Unity, so the List wouldn't yet have been initialized.